# Filter wp_remote_get using metadata

Tags: php, wordpress, api, rest

I have created 2 sites, MAIN site contains all the content of a custom post type 'establishment' that has custom metadata. Now on the 2nd site I'm using **wp_remote_get()** to retrieve the custom post from the MAIN site.

Everything is working as intended and the metadata is showing in the response on the 2nd site under [meta].

Now trying to find a way to filter the results of **wp_remote_get()** according to the mate data. For example **wp_remote_get()** only returns establishment's (custom post) that does contains the set metadata.

I have tried looking into adding it to the URL but can't find any information on it or know if it is even possible.

Comment: Can you show a sample of the URLs that you are using?

Comment: @ChrisHaas This is one example /wp-json/wp/v2/establishment?country=1764,1804&page=1&per_page=9&_embed

Comment: I think [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/332317/12496) is what you are looking for